Why does my selectedvalue not change, and the form is not showing?
Here I add a global function to change it, because I need them in the next case. But both things are not working.
Widget form(String? num) {
  return Container(
    width: screenWidth*0.7,
    height: screenHeight*0.3,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 85, 107, 47),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
    ),
    child:Text('какая-та форма {$num}')
  );
}

List<Widget> getForm() {
  List<Widget> forms = [];
  for(int i=1; i<selectedCount; i++) {
    forms.add(form(i.toString()));
  }
  return forms;
}

void onChanged(int? value) {
  setState(() {
    selectedCount = value ?? selectedCount;
  });
}

DropdownButton<int>(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.white),
                      iconSize: 20,
                      value: selectedCount,
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        items: List.generate(6, (index) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                          value: index,
                          child: Text(index.toString()),
                          )
                        ),
                        onChanged:onChanged,
                    ),

In this case my options aren't changing.

does selectedCount is declared within build method ? if so, declare it in class level.

Oh... I initialized it widget build method. Thanks
